# html select option in angular.js how to make correct ng if?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have scope in controller: `$scope.readOnly = true`
then I have code in html:

```
  <select ng-if="readOnly" ng-model="readOnly" required>
     <option value="true" selected>True</option>
     <option value="false">False</option>
  </select>

 <select ng-if="!readOnly" ng-model="readOnly" required>
     <option value="true">True</option>
     <option value="false" selected>False</option>
 </select>

<button ng-click="save()"> Save</button>
```

but it doesn't work fine :/ on click save, the result is undefined :/ how to make this correct?

Comment: can you please post more of your HTML code and the JS controller as well?

Comment: @Ironcar Driftman, Initialize $scope.doc.readOnly to true instead of specifiying selected in option.

Comment: Please add controller and complete HTML or share it as a plunkr

Comment: @RajKantaria Initialize `$scope.doc.readOnly` dosen't work, because you must to initialize `$scope.doc` as an object. Correct initialize: `$scope.doc = { readOnly: true };`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kakv0huf/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try do this in this way:

```
<select ng-model="doc.readOnly">
   <option value=true>True</option>
   <option value=false>False</option>
</select>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kakv0huf/)

Comment: paste an example in jsfiddle.net

Comment: jsfiddle.net/kakv0huf/1

Comment: it doesn't work in my code and can you come in my computer with team viewer?